# Adding arrows to axes using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using `axis lines=middle` in the brackets after `\begin{axis}`, I can get arrows to appear on the x and y axes of a graph in the positive but not the negative direction. How do I add arrows in the negative direction?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={before end axis/.append code={\draw[dashed,<->,>=latex] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0}); }}}

\begin{tikzpicture} %cscx

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
 axis lines=middle,
 ticklabel style={fill=white},
 x=.7cm,y=.7cm,clip=false,
 xmin=-3.5,xmax=4.5,xtick={-2,2,4},
 ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,ytick={-4,-2,2,4},
 minor tick={-3,-1,1,3},
 vasymptote={-pi+0.5},vasymptote={0.5},vasymptote={pi+0.5},
 xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
 xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
 ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
 samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-2.39:0.25,<->,>=latex] {cosec(deg(x-0.5))};
\addplot[domain=0.75:3.39,<->,>=latex] {cosec(deg(x-0.5))};
\node[label={270:{\(y=\csc x\)}},inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5,-4.5) {};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new style in `\pgfplotsset` called for example `myaxis`, define the arrow style there and then add the style's name to the axis options.

Also, I added `arrows.meta` which is the new library for the arrow tips in Tikz.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    vasymptote/.style={before end axis/.append code={\draw[dashed,<->,-{Latex}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0}); }},
    myaxis/.style={axis line style={<->, {Latex}-{Latex}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} %cscx

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
 axis lines=middle,
 myaxis,
 ticklabel style={fill=white},
 x=.7cm,y=.7cm,clip=false,
 xmin=-3.5,xmax=4.5,xtick={-2,2,4},
 ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,ytick={-4,-2,2,4},
 minor tick={-3,-1,1,3},
 vasymptote={-pi+0.5},vasymptote={0.5},vasymptote={pi+0.5},
 xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
 xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
 ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
 samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-2.39:0.25,<->,>=latex] {cosec(deg(x-0.5))};
\addplot[domain=0.75:3.39,<->,>=latex] {cosec(deg(x-0.5))};
\node[label={270:{\(y=\csc x\)}},inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5,-4.5) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```